# Using ASPNET vNext in production is a good idea?

Tags: asp.net-core

Aspnet vnext is still in beta version, and we are about to start a new application, and we considering to using aspnet vnext, i would like to know if it is a good a idea, someone is already running application in production with vnext?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you can wear the risk of implementing a project on an unfinished framework.  Items that affect this risk include;

- Expected size of your application
- Other libraries you intend to use
- Platform you intend to target
- Whether you can afford the learning curve (there are changes)
- Whether you are happy to spend time upgrading when its finally released
- Whether you want to deal with implementing workarounds when you find features that are not working as expected.